# Change Date Format on Date Range Filter in crud

Tags: laravel-backpack

How can one change the date format on a date range filter in backpack?

I have tried the following:

```
'date_range_options' => [
            'locale' => ['format' => 'DD/MM/YYYY']`enter code here`
        ]
```

but it does not work. Format stays MM/DD/YYYY

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Daterangepicker options are hardcoded, so I made a copy of vendor/backpack/crud/src/resources/views/filters/date_range.blade.php
in my project:
resources/views/vendor/backpack/crud/filters/date_range.blade.php

Then you have to add to daterangepicker config:

```
locale: {
                format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
        }
```